# Emacs behind firewall cannot download packages from Melpa

Tags: package-repositories, upgrade, proxy

I am using emacs behind a firewall in Windows. I configured the access to proxy and I worked with no problems for a week. But now I can't upgrade emacs packages using Melpa, because the proxy refuses to download packages ("Bad request"). Any clue to what may happened?

This is the result of emacs with `--init-debug`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/archive-contents" "Bad Request")
  signal(file-error ("http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/archive-contents" "Bad Request"))
  url-insert-file-contents("http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/archive-contents")
  package--download-one-archive(("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") "archive-contents")
  #[0 "\301\300\302\"\207" [("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") package--download-one-archive "archive-contents"] 3 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  funcall(#[0 "\301\300\302\"\207" [("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") package--download-one-archive "archive-contents"] 3 "\n\n(fn)"])
  package-refresh-contents()
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/sergio.bacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 8124
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/sergio.bacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" "c:/Users/sergio.bacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("c:/Users/sergio.bacelar/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262
```

Comment: @lunaryorn: Please consider posting that as an answer. The question is good (helpful), as is the answer.

Comment: @Drew Ok, I'll replace my comment with an answer.

Comment: I have the same problem, and it persists even after changing to `https://melpa.org/packages/`. It appears that Emacs is sending a `GET https://...` request to the proxy, which gets a 400 Bad Request response. On the other hand, wget sends a `CONNECT melpa.org:443` request to the proxy, and manages to download the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you're using is outdated; MELPA now serves from https://melpa.org.  Please replace `("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")` in your `package-archives` with `("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")`.  Then restart Emacs and try again.

Should the error still occur, please try `curl https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents` or `wget https://melpa.org/packages/archive-contents` to check whether the error comes from Emacs' or from the proxy server.  If curl/wget return a bad request as well please contact the administrator of the proxy server.

Also note that [MELPA had some downtime recently](https://github.com/melpa/melpa/issues/4156) so you may want to try again in a couple of days if you're still getting the error after changing the URLs.

Comment: Solved, after changing (in my Windows Emacs version) http://melpa.milkbox.net to http://melpa.org. What I am failing to understand is why the old address (melpa.milkbox.net) works in OSX (not behind a firewall) but not in Windows (behind a firewall)...

Comment: @sbac I don't know either, but MELPA is still having issues currently so unless you tried at the very same time it might as well have been a connection issue.  Maybe MELPA timed out and the (misconfigured) proxy turned it into a 400?  Hard to say with so little information.